# Velocity from velocity profile

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fluid-dynamics

I have this homework question and I get a different answer to the solutions.

In Cylindrical polar coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$, the velocity potential of a flow is given by:

$$\phi = -\frac{Ua^2r}{b^2-a^2}(1+\frac{b^2}{r^2})cos\theta$$

Find the velocity.

I get the velocity as:

$$v = (-\frac{Ua^2}{b^2-a^2}(1+\frac{b^2}{r^2})cos\theta + \frac{2Ua^2b^2}{(b^2-a^2)r^2}cos\theta)e_r + (\frac{Ua^2}{b^2-a^2}(1+\frac{b^2}{r^2})sin\theta) e_{\theta}$$

The answer misses out the second term in the $r$ direction, but I can't see where I've gone wrong. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could correct velocity profile and use velocity potential instead, I believe that's what you meant.

Comment: I did mean potential. Thanks for that and confirmation of the answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct!

Maybe they gathered the term in the solution as below ( and maybe made an error of sign).

$$v = (-\frac{Ua^2}{b^2-a^2}(1-\frac{b^2}{r^2})cos\theta) e_{r} + (\frac{Ua^2}{b^2-a^2}(1+\frac{b^2}{r^2})sin\theta) e_{\theta}$$